# Expectation of a matrix over random vectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, real-numbers

Suppose I have a matrix A which is for argument's sake 3 by 3 and has  different eigenvalues, let's say 1, 2 and 3. If I was to generate vectors on a unitary sphere $\eta$ and then calculate the dot product:
$$\frac{\eta^{\dagger}A\eta}{\eta^{\dagger}\eta}$$

and then represent that on the real number line, would I get increases of the density of "hits" near the known eigenvalues, or would it be something else?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Some people call what you are doing *numerical range*. Honestly I would change the title. There is also this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4810 which deals with the the selfadjoint case (sorry for the self-promotion).

Comment: Note also that in order for your *average* to be real you need the matrix to be hermitian

Comment: @lcv Thanks for the comment I edited the title. Yes I forgot to mention that, matrix A is hermitian.

Comment: @lcv when $A$ is Hermitian, it seems your paper tell us the PDF of the ratio is a triangle distribution (vanishes at $\lambda = 1,3$ and peaked at $2$).

Comment: @achillehui yes. In general the PDF is a piecewise smooth function. The eigenvalues are the location where the pieces are joined together. The smoothness is given by the total dimension (and possibly the degeneracy, if I remember well).